# How to Create a JSON Restful Web Service in C#/ASP with MySQL as Db?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, json, rest

I followed [This](http://www.asp.net/web-api/tutorials/hands-on-labs/build-restful-apis-with-aspnet-web-api) to Create a RESTful Web Service which Displays Json as output

So that I can use this JSON in the part of Mobile application,

But Here Actually I have a Lot of data to display I am Creating a Server Side for mobile application so I decided to Store My data in the part of Mysql I successfully stored

But I failed to Display the JSON data As out Put..
Any suggestion regarding this.. please tell me some reference links.,..

Comment: Browsers tend to default to xml, try using a tool such as postman to make the call to your Web API. If it still comes back as xml, specify content type as "application/json" and you should receive the response in json.
NB: My comment assumes you are already successful in obtaining a response from your endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply [create](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/201901/CREATE-RESTful-WCF-Service-API-Using-POST-Step-By) a simple c# rest web service. To return json data , you will need to specify the return data format on specific operation in the web service.  To use mysql for database, you can search for mysql connector for c# on google. You can find libraries to use  in your code. Hope it helps !